# Why my screen is not showing correctly

Tags: windows-7, display

My laptop monitor shows screens like this:
[[image: Monitor Pic]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVge0.png)

there are lines to the bottom of the page which moves along with windows.(pay attention to photo)

please share your opinions and help

Comment: I can't seem to see any lines as you describe. If that's the same for anyone else (and I'm not just missing it entirely), it sounds like an issue with your physical screen, as Windows must be generating the content correctly otherwise the print screen would display the issue as well. Can you look at the screenshot from another device, to make sure that the issue is visible in the screenshot and, if so, point out exactly where it is?

Comment: The easiest way to test it would be to plug in another monitor if you have one to hand. That way you're using the same machine but taking the screen out of the equation.

Comment: Maybe you could circle them :-) I think whatever your referrring to is some sort of artifact in the rendering hardware.

Answer (score 1):

That is the effect of the theme you have applied. Nothing related to your hardware monitor. Change the theme the line will go automatically. You have applied the basic them.